# PowerShell script failure on remote execution

Tags: powershell

On executing a PowerShell Remote Script I am getting an error like following

> Invoke-Command : Exception calling "ToXmlString" with "1" argument(s):
>   "The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be
>   trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured
>   to allow delegation.

The exact line of code the execution is breaking is as follows:

```
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$key = $rsa.ToXmlString($true)
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Comment: This is a question I already asked in StackExchange and I got the following links as answer
    * How do I configure accounts so that they are trusted for delegation in a Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition environment? - http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-7359-how-do-i-configure-accounts-so-that-they-are-trusted-for-delegation-in-a-windows-server-2003-enterprise-edition-environment-
    * Kerberos authentication and troubleshooting delegation issues - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907272
Unfortunately this doesn't work and please suggest if any other options more to be done

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable credential delegation, so that PowerShell can pass your username/password to the remote computer, so that it can use them to perform the operation which is failing.  [See this answer on StackOverflow for instructions/details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362057/what-security-setting-is-preventing-remote-powershell-2-0-from-accessing-unc-pat/8436654#8436654)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that this was a remote script. I have a couple questions to try narrowing down the issue:

- Can you run these two commands locally on the computer?
- Is the remote computer in the same domain as the computer you're trying to run this?
- Is this error specific to a user and/or computer (local and remote)?
- Are you able to run any PowerShell commands on the remote computer? (Get-Process, Get-Host, etc.)

If you are able to run the commands locally, or are unable to test running the commands directly on the remote machine try running the following command from an elevated *Command Prompt* (CMD, not PowerShell) to have PowerShell explicitly trust the remote computer:

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputer"}'
```

I'll try to edit this answer toward being a real true "answer" rather than a comment, since I'm not able to comment on your question directly.